# How to add "name" attribute to <mat-cell> or <mat-row> with a dynamic value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a `mat-table` which is rendering around 10 rows at a time. The data source for this table comes from an API call as an array of objects. I want to add a `name` attribute to the `mat-cell` element inside it or to the `mat-row` element with the value as a string concatenated with the index of that row.

I am able to get the index through `*matCellDef="let i = index"` and `*matRowDef="let i = index;"` respectively. But if I add the `name` attribute with value as `name="monitoring{{i}}"` then it just doesnt add the attribute to that tag/element. But if I remove the `{{i}}` from the value(which makes it `name="monitoring"`) then it will be assigned the string and would display perfectly but the name for each row becomes the same.

Does anyone know how to assign dynamic values to name property and what am I doing wrong here in the assignment such that it doesnt show up on dynamic value assignment?

Thankz in advance.

P.S This is the code that I am trying with -

> Doesnt work :(
>
> `<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;" name="monitoring{{i}}"></mat-row>`
>
> Works
>
> `<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" name="monitoring"></mat-row>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. So I found out that the problem was with how `<mat-cell>` and `<mat-row>` accept and operate on `name` attribute. So this got fixed when I used `[attr.name]` instead of `name` or `[name]`.

The final assignment expression -

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index" [attr.name]="'monitoring'+i">{{i}}</mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use name as Object Input: `[name]="'monitoring' + i"`;